# Plaid integration Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, plaid

I would like to make a payment using *Stripe ACH*.

I use gem `plaid`.

Here is my Link code:

```
var linkHandler = Plaid.create({
    clientName: 'Some Name',
    env: 'sandbox',
    key: ENV['key'],
    product: ['auth'],
    onSuccess: function(public_token, metadata) {
        $.post('/plaid/set_auth', {
            public_token: public_token,
            account: metadata.account_id
        });

        console.log('Public Token: ' + public_token);
        console.log('Selected account ID: ' + metadata.account_id);
    }
});
```

Plaid controller:

```
def set_auth
  public_token = params['public_token']
  account_id   = params['account']

  client = Plaid::Client.new(env: :sandbox, 
                       client_id: ENV['client_id'],
                          secret: ENV['secret'],
                      public_key: ENV['public_key'])

  exchange_token_response = client.item.public_token.exchange(public_token)
  access_token = exchange_token_response.access_token


  #Create a Stripe bank_account_token

  stripe_response = client.processor.stripe.bank_account_token.create(access_token, account_id)
  bank_account_token = stripe_response.stripe_bank_account_token

  customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("<customer-id>")

  customer.sources.create({
    :source => bank_account_token
  })

  #...Stripe::Charge.create()...
end
```

**The problem** is that `metadata.account_id` parameter is not passed to controller.

Browser console: `Selected account ID: null`

If i do `puts client.accounts.get(access_token)` I get several accounts with different balances.

[image: accounts]

Comment: Have you tried to print public_token and metadata in the console? Check the values.

Comment: `public_token` is working correctly.

Comment: What's in public_token? Can the metadata be in public_token?

Comment: `public_token = public-sandbox-ce9c11...` and
`metadata = {"institution"=>{"name"=>"Chase", "institution_id"=>"ins_3"}, "account"=>{"id"=>"", "name"=>"", "type"=>"", "subtype"=>"", "mask"=>""}, "account_id"=>"", "accounts"=>{"0"=>{"id"=>"PG7xK5xVJ5tqe...", "name"=>"Plaid Checking", "mask"=>"0000", "type"=>"depository", "subtype"=>"checking"},..`

Comment: @demir `metadata` same as picture in my question.

Comment: From plaid documantation: "The metadata object contains info about the institution the user selected and the account ID or IDs, if the Select Account view is enabled."
Did you enable `Select Account` view  from dashboard?

Comment: @demir Thank you very much!
I re-read the documentation, but didn't find it. Included account selection, now I have  ID.

Answer (score 0):

Enable `Select Account` view from Plaid dashboard.