# Plaid + Stripe ACH integration failure - account_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I'm trying to integrate Plaid w/ Stripe to add ACH source to a Stripe Customer (not Stripe Account).

I followed the instructions here https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid

Calling `stripe_response = client.Processor.stripeBankAccountTokenCreate(access_token, account_id)` results in an error
`account_id must be a properly formatted, non-empty string`

The second argument `account_id` is `cus_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and not `acct_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`.

Comment: Are you passing the account ID to the server in the onSuccess callback of Plaid.create with the public token?

Comment: I realized what my mistake was. It's explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373656/plaid-integration-rails